# Handle same Object from different (Web)services

Tags: c#, web-services

In my project I'm using 2 Webservices (lets call em `servA`and `servB`) which return the same type of object.

The object looks as follows:

```
public class Record
{
        public String RecordName{ get; set; }
        public List<RecordAttribute> RecordAttributes{ get; set; }
}

public class RecordAttribute
{
        public String AttributeName{ get; set; }
        public List<object> RecordAttributesValues{ get; set; }
}
```

I've written a generic piece of code to map those RecordAttributes to a local Objecttype. But the problem i'm facing is `I have to keep seperate functions for the results coming from servA Aand servB.`

e.g. as follows:

for ServA

```
public List<T> mapServAResultToObject<T>(ServA.Record[] results)
{ 
     .... 
     mapServAAttributeToObject<T>(results.RecordAttributes)
     ....
}
Public T mapServBAttributesToObject<T>(ServA.RecordAttribute Attrs)
{ .... }
```

for servB

```
public List<T> mapServBResultToObject<T>(ServB.Record[] results)
{ 
     .... 
     mapServBAttributesToObject<T>(results.RecordAttributes)
     ....
}
Public T mapServBAttributesToObject<T>(ServB.RecordAttribute Attrs)
{ .... }
```

These double function are starting to hurt my eyes.
**Question:**

1. Is there a way around this, that i can just use a single function for both the results of ServA and ServB
2. Or is there a performance-wise efficient way to cast those results to a fast localobject?

And this without adaptations to the services?

Comment: Are the property names same in ServA.record and ServB.record? And do you want to map all things automatically?

Comment: @Mino Yes they are completly the same(fields, properties,type). Only the webservice where the object originates from is different.

Comment: Can we use automapper?

Comment: If you have control over the web services, I say try converting them to WCF and push the Record type to a separate dll.  That way you can reference the dll with Record type defined from client applications and when adding a service reference you can reuse existing type.

Comment: @Mino You can use automapper yes. Although i don't have any experience in using it

Comment: @SaiPuli wouldn't that still give the same problem? As far as I could tell, the compiler would still regard em as different objects as the origin of the objects still remains different?

Comment: Can you create an interface for those ServerA and B, then make them implement it, and make the method accept the interface?

Comment: @adminSoftDK the problem is in the other direction :) . If i recieve an object which implements your interface from ServerA or ServerB, then according to the compiler those objects would implement a different interface

Comment: It would not.  This is a WCF feature not available for web services. You will implement the classes/types in a separate dll and use them in service. Then you distribute just the dll with types to the clients via email or nuget or another medium.  Then on the client, first add reference to the dll with types defined. Then while adding service reference you would go into the advanced settings and select "Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies" and select the library in the list below that.  This will make both service clients use the same exact type.

Comment: When you say "web service" do you mean a .asmx web service? Because WCF _is_ web services. Also, do you have two copies of the same web service, or do they just happen to share a similar class? Are they in the same XML namespace in the WSDL? Finally, if they _are_ in the same namespace, you can still use "Add Service Reference" on the client side and you can still put the shared type into a DLL and use the same type for both services.

Comment: @JohnSaunders actually in my case ServA is an asmx and ServB is an WCF. Problem (bear with me because its hard to explain) is ServA is an older version of ServB. We cannot just 'ditch' ServA because it is not ready yet to completely be transferred to ServB. But as `Record`is in fact in the same namespace, i'll ook into what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mapping example done with AutoMapper. It can map ServA and ServB objects into ObjectType. You can get AutoMapper from Nuget.

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var objectFromServiceA = new ServA_Record();
            objectFromServiceA.RecordAttributes = new List<ServA_Record.ServA_RecordAttribute>();
            objectFromServiceA.RecordName = "Test A";
            objectFromServiceA.RecordAttributes.Add(new ServA_Record.ServA_RecordAttribute() { AttributeName = "Record Attr A", RecordAttributesValues = new List<object>() });

            var objectFromServiceB = new ServB_Record();
            objectFromServiceB.RecordAttributes = new List<ServB_Record.ServB_RecordAttribute>();
            objectFromServiceB.RecordName = "Test B";
            objectFromServiceB.RecordAttributes.Add(new ServB_Record.ServB_RecordAttribute() { AttributeName = "Record Attr B", RecordAttributesValues = new List<object>() });

            var businessObject = new ObjectType();

            Mapper.CreateMap<ServA_Record, ObjectType>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ServB_Record, ObjectType>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ServA_Record.ServA_RecordAttribute, ObjectType.ObjectTypeAttribute>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ServB_Record.ServB_RecordAttribute, ObjectType.ObjectTypeAttribute>();

            businessObject = Mapper.Map<ServA_Record, ObjectType>(objectFromServiceA);
            Console.WriteLine(businessObject.RecordName);
            Console.WriteLine(businessObject.RecordAttributes[0].AttributeName);

            businessObject = Mapper.Map<ServB_Record, ObjectType>(objectFromServiceB);
            Console.WriteLine(businessObject.RecordName);
            Console.WriteLine(businessObject.RecordAttributes[0].AttributeName);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class ServA_Record
    {
        public String RecordName { get; set; }
        public List<ServA_RecordAttribute> RecordAttributes { get; set; }

        public class ServA_RecordAttribute
        {
            public String AttributeName { get; set; }
            public List<object> RecordAttributesValues { get; set; }
        }
    }

    public class ServB_Record
    {
        public String RecordName { get; set; }
        public List<ServB_RecordAttribute> RecordAttributes { get; set; }

        public class ServB_RecordAttribute
        {
            public String AttributeName { get; set; }
            public List<object> RecordAttributesValues { get; set; }
        }
    }

    public class ObjectType
    {
        public String RecordName { get; set; }
        public List<ObjectTypeAttribute> RecordAttributes { get; set; }

        public class ObjectTypeAttribute
        {
            public String AttributeName { get; set; }
            public List<object> RecordAttributesValues { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you understood the question perfectly :). I'll try to make my own implementation following your example and i'll get back to you.

Comment: Automapper uses naming conventions in mapping so it doesn't depend on base classes or interfaces. It contains also other powerful features for DTO mapping. Glad it helped